# Unable to generate javadoc in Eclipse for linked source files

Tags: eclipse, javadoc, eclipse-mars

I am unable to generate javadoc for linked .java files using Eclipse Mars.

This shows how my project is set up:
[image: Eclipse view]

I am able to run the program.

The source file is in a folder named `foo`, to match the package declaration:

[image: Directory Ellen > Google Drive > 64 2016 > src > foo]

I select `Project > Generate Javadoc...` and check the package:

[image]

I agree to all of the default options.

I get this output in the console:

```
Loading source files for package foo...
Constructing Javadoc information...
javadoc: warning - No source files for package foo
javadoc: warning - No source files for package foo
javadoc: error - No public or protected classes found to document.
1 error
2 warnings
```

Adding javadoc comments to the source code makes no difference.

I have no trouble generating javadoc when I do not have linked source files.

How do I set up links to source files so I can generate javadoc?

Comment: If you create a `src` folder and than put links under appropriate package. Than it will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `Project > Generate Javadoc...` it launches the external program `javadoc` part of the JDK typically. The `javadoc` program does not understand/know about Eclipse linked resources, so it sees the empty folder.

> How do I set up links to source files so I can generate javadoc?

Short answer is you cannot with links at the file level.

### Use Links to *src* folder

Rather than doing a link to files within a package, make the link to the containing source folder. In your screenshot you don't have a *src* folder, but you could create one that is linked.

For example, I have a project called `demoforso`, in it I create a folder called `src` that is linked to `D:\tmp\src` and add `src` to classpath. When the javadoc is run on this project, it passes `D:\tmp\src` as the sourcepath.

### Use Javadoc views in Eclipse

(i.e. Don't generate Javadoc at all, granted possibly not useful in your case, but included for completeness.)

The hovers and `Javadoc` view in Eclipse means that you never need to generated Javadoc for your own use.

Comment: Thanks so much for the helpful response. I'll give it a try when I get home.

Comment: I'm having trouble figuring out how to link an entire src folder. Any pointers?

Comment: Actually, I got it working by creating a new project with separate folders for src and class files, then dragging in the src file, selecting the option "Link to files and recreate folder structure with virtual folders", and overwriting the existing src directory. The display of packages is a little awkward but works.